# Select percentage of another column in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, percentage

I would like to select, grouped by avfamily, the amount of records that have livingofftheland value equalling true and return it as the perc value.

Essentially column 3 divided by column 2 times 100.

```
select 

    avclassfamily, 
    count(distinct(malware_id)) as cc, 
    sum(case when livingofftheland = 'true' then 1 else 0 end),  
    (100.0 *  (sum(case when livingofftheland = 'true' then 1 else 0 end)  / (count(*)) ) )  as perc 
from malwarehashesandstrings 
group by avclassfamily  having count(*) > 5000  
order by perc desc;
```

Probably quite simple but my brains drawing a blank here.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: `distinct` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `count(distinct malware_id) as cc` to make code clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> select, grouped by `avfamily`, the amount of records that have `livingofftheland` value equalling `true` and return it as the perc value.

You could simply use `avg()` for this:

```
select 
    avclassfamily, 
    count(distinct(malware_id)) as cc, 
    avg(livingofftheland::int) * 100 as perc 
from malwarehashesandstrings 
group by avclassfamily
having count(*) > 5000
order by perc desc
```

`livingofftheland::int` turns the boolean value to `0` (false) or `1` (true). The average of this value gives you the ratio of records that satisfy the condition in the group, as a decimal number between `0` and `1`, thatn you can then multiply by `100`.

Answer (score 1):

I would express this as:

```
select avclassfamily, 
       count(distinct malware_id) as cc, 
       count(*) filter (where livingofftheland = 'true'),
       ( count(*) filter (where livingofftheland = 'true') * 100.0 /
         count(distinct malware_id)
       ) as perc
from malwarehashesandstrings 
group by avclassfamily 
having count(*) > 5000  
order by perc desc;
```

Note that this replaces the conditional aggregation with `filter`, a SQL standard construct that Postgres supports. It also puts the `100.0` right next to the `/`, just to be sure Postgres doesn't decide to do integer division.